# How should I escape image URLs for CSS?

Tags: css, url, escaping, xss

I have a `div` which will receive a CSS background image from user chosen URL, like so:

`background-image: url("/* user specified URL here*/")`

How should I escape the URL so that it's safe to embed in the CSS? Is escaping the quotes enough?

Comment: You'll probably also want to URLENCODE it (convert spaces to %20, etc.)

Comment: @SetSailMedia Encoding the entire URL with a funciton like `urlencode` will break the URL.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara good point! guess OP will have to use some smart filtering, then :)

Comment: It should be noted that some older browsers will execute `background-image: url('javascript:SOME_JS_CODE')`. Escaping quotes won't save those browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is escaping the quotes enough?

No, you also should worry about backslashes and newlines.

Here is the CSS grammar for a double quoted URI:
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html#scanner

```
"([^\n\r\f\\"]|\\{nl}|{escape})"
```

where `{nl}` is

```
\n|\r\n|\r|\f
```

and `{escape}` is a backslash-escaped character. So a trailing backslash will break your CSS. A non-escaped newline likewise.

I would strongly recommend to remove all whitespace and finally escape `"` and `\`

Answer (score 18):

If you are setting the background url through JS, then the correct and safe ways is using encodeURI() and wrapping in quotes.

```
node.style.backgroundImage = 'url("' + encodeURI(url) + '")';
```

Comment: The generalized, non-JS version of this answer is that to escape a URL for CSS, you only need to URL-encode (`"` => `%22`) the characters that are neither "reserved" nor "unreserved" in URLs ([RFC 3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986)). That is what `encodeURI()` does. This works because well-formed URLs do not contain any characters that are unsafe in CSS strings, except for apostrophe (`'`), which is why you should use double quotes (`"`) for your CSS string. It won't break a URL that wasn't broken to begin with.

Comment: beware of brackets `()`, they are not escaped with `encodeURI`

Comment: @BasselShmali Since the url() contents are wrapped in quotes, I don't think that should be an issue.

Comment: @MārtiņšBriedis Holy Molly, I missed that

Comment: encodeURI won't work if the url already contains escape sequences because it escapes %, so `%20` becomes `%2520`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Since the user data that you need to insert into CSS can be treated like a URL, and not just a string, you only need to ensure that it is properly URL-encoded.

This is safe because a well-formed URL does not contain any characters that are unsafe in CSS strings; except for apostrophe (`'`), which is not a problem as long as you use double quotes for your CSS string: `url("...")`

A simple way to do this is to URL-encode all characters that are not "reserved" or "unreserved" in URLs. According to [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2), that would be all characters except for these:

```
A-Z a-z 0-9 ; , / ? : @ & = + $ - _ . ! ~ * ' ( ) # [ ]
```

That is what [`encodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) does in [Mārtiņš Briedis's JavaScript answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25613552/how-should-i-escape-image-urls-for-css/33541245#33541245). (With one exception: `encodeURI()` encodes `[` and `]`, which is mostly inconsequential.)

In addition to that, you might consider only allowing URLs that begin with `https:` or `data:`. By doing this you can prevent [mixed content warnings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content) if the page is served over HTTPS, and also avoid the `javascript:` issue [Alexander O'Mara commented on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25613552/how-should-i-escape-image-urls-for-css/25613795#comment40013491_25613552).

There might be other URL parsing and validation that you want to do, but that is outside the scope of this question.

If you need to insert user data into a CSS string that cannot be treated like a URL, then you would need to do [CSS backslash escaping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/string). See [user123444555621's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25613552/how-should-i-escape-image-urls-for-css/25613795#25613795) for more on that.

Answer (score 3):

```
const style = "background-image: url(\"" + CSS.escape(imageUrl) + "\")";
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/escape

It is an experimental new thing, but it seems to be quite well supported (as of 2021).